# Creating Enum vs Nullable bool for readability?

Tags: c#

Which one is more verbose?

```
private bool? _hasChangesToReconcile;
public bool HasChanges()
{
    if (!_hasChangesToReconcile.HasValue)
    {
        if (Model != null)
        {
            using (var broker = _documentBrokerDelegateFactory())
            {
                  return broker.Value.HasSectionChanges(Model.Id);
                _hasChangesToReconcile = broker.Value.HasSectionChanges(Model.Id);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _hasChangesToReconcile = false;
        }
    }
    return _hasChangesToReconcile.Value;
} 

public void Handle(PageSectionVersionsCreated message)
{
    if (!message.ChangesApplyTo(Model))
        return;
    _hasChangesToReconcile = null;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ItemType);
}
```

or

```
private State _pageStatus;
private enum PageStatus
{
    HasChanges,
    NoChanges,
}
private bool _hasChanges;
public bool HasChanges()
{
    if (_pageStatus == PageStatus.HasChanges)
    {
        if (Model != null)
        {
            using (var broker = _documentBrokerDelegateFactory())
            {
                _hasChanges = broker.Value.HasSectionChanges(Model.Id);
            }
        }
    }
    return _hasChanges;
} 

public void Handle(PageSectionVersionsCreated message)
{
    if (!message.ChangesApplyTo(Model))
        return;
    _pageStatus = PageStatus.HasChanges;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ItemType);
    _pageStatus = PageStatus.NoChanges;
}
```

Comment: Your nullable boolean can be null, obviously, which means it has three possible states, while your enum only has two. What was your intent?

Comment: @Magus An enum can be null as well.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg not in C#, it has to be declared as a `Nullable<MyEnumType>`.

Comment: `private State _pageStatus` doesn't seem to be the same type as `PageStatus`. Shouldn't it be `private PageStatus _pageStatus;` or `private PageStatus? _pageStatus;`?

Comment: @Magus Exactly my question, what was the intent of the nullable if it will only end up with two states? I was proposing to my coworker an enum instead of using nullables

Comment: No, as @Mat'sMug said, both `bool` and `Enum` are value types. An enum with two states is equivalent to a boolean, except that it is integral. A flags enum would let you have more states, but it would not limit them. Currently, your nullable boolean has more possible values than your enum.

Comment: @Magus The 2nd version has an enum *and* a non-nullable bool.

Comment: That's downright horrific. There's a method named the same thing as an enum value right there. I'd just make an enum with three states...

Comment: @Magus The 3 enum state names would be "HasChanges", "NoChanges", and "DontKnowUntilItsRecalculated"; so I prefer the `bool?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of the two fragments is slightly different:

- In the 2nd you `_pageStatus = PageStatus.NoChanges;` in the `Handle` method
- In the first you set a non-null value in the `HasChanges` method

To make them equal the 2nd implementation should be like this:

```
public bool HasChanges()
{
    if (_pageStatus == PageStatus.HasChanges)
    {
        _pageStatus = PageStatus.NoChanges;
        if (Model != null)
        {
            using (var broker = _documentBrokerDelegateFactory())
            {
                _hasChanges = broker.Value.HasSectionChanges(Model.Id);
            }
        }
    }
    return _hasChanges;
} 

public void Handle(PageSectionVersionsCreated message)
{
    if (!message.ChangesApplyTo(Model))
        return;
    _pageStatus = PageStatus.HasChanges;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ItemType);
}
```

---

Your two-state enum could be another boolean, e.g. `bool _resetHasChanges`.

---

I find that having two related variables is more verbose than having a single `bool?` variable, especially when the 2nd enum variable is just tracking whether the first variable has an assigned value.

Comment: So you prefer enum more than the single bool?

Comment: "Verbose" means "too many words" or "saying something simple in a complicated way". I prefer `bool?` because it's simpler, more expressive, and less likely to go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

this code here can be simplified

> ```
> if (!_hasChangesToReconcile.HasValue)
> {
>     if (Model != null)
>     {
>         using (var broker = _documentBrokerDelegateFactory())
>         {
>             _hasChangesToReconcile = broker.Value.HasSectionChanges(Model.Id);
>         }
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         _hasChangesToReconcile = false;
>     }
> }
> return _hasChangesToReconcile.Value;
> ```

so that you return inside the if statement which is clearer to what is going on and performs less operations

```
if (!_hasChangesToReconcile.HasValue)
{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        using (var broker = _documentBrokerDelegateFactory())
        {
            return broker.Value.HasSectionChanges(Model.Id);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

if there was a loop here where there was more than one Change to reconcile I could see doing it the other way, but as is, this code is cleaner and more to the point.

---

Same thing with this bit of code from the second set of code

> ```
> if (_pageStatus == PageStatus.HasChanges)
> {
>     if (Model != null)
>     {
>         using (var broker = _documentBrokerDelegateFactory())
>         {
>             _hasChanges = broker.Value.HasSectionChanges(Model.Id);
>         }
>     }
> }
> return _hasChanges;
> ```

you should just return `broker.Value.HasSectionChanges(Model.Id)`  like this

```
if (_pageStatus == PageStatus.HasChanges)
{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        using (var broker = _documentBrokerDelegateFactory())
        {
            return broker.Value.HasSectionChanges(Model.Id);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Something else that I noticed:

both sets of code use a negative conditional inside the if statement of the Handle Method

> ```
> public void Handle(PageSectionVersionsCreated message)
> {
>   if (!message.ChangesApplyTo(Model))
>       return;
>   _pageStatus = PageStatus.HasChanges;
>   NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ItemType);
>     _pageStatus = PageStatus.NoChanges;
> }
> ```

this should be rewritten to express this in terms of a positive.
it should look like this:

```
public void Handle(PageSectionVersionsCreated message)
{
    if (message.ChangesApplyTo(Model))
    {
        _pageStatus = PageStatus.HasChanges;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ItemType);
        _pageStatus = PageStatus.NoChanges;
    }
}
```

since you aren't returning anything anyways, this is the more logical approach,  and it looks way cleaner.

---

**So I guess that you could say that they are both Verbose**

Answer (score 1):

in the first code block you have code that is unreachable

```
using (var broker = _documentBrokerDelegateFactory())
{
    return broker.Value.HasSectionChanges(Model.Id);
    _hasChangesToReconcile = broker.Value.HasSectionChanges(Model.Id);
}
```

`hasChangesToReconcile` is never set to `broker.Value.HasSectionChanges(Model.Id)`

if you need that set, you should do it before the return.